# Entire function and the Exponential function

Tags: complex-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Given an entire function $f : f(z)=f'(z) \forall z \in \Bbb C$, I need to prove that $\exists c \in \Bbb C : f(z)=ce^z$.

Even though it seems very intuitive I could not prove it completely. My reasoning so far:

Since $f'=f$ then $f'= \frac{\partial}{\partial x}u(x,y)+i\frac{\partial}{\partial x}u(x,y)=u(x,y)+v(x,y)=f$, so $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}u(x,y)=u(x,y)$ and $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}(v(x,y))=v(x,y)$ for both $u$ and $v$. Therefore both $\frac{\partial }{\partial x}(v(x,y))$ and $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}(u(x,y))$ are real valued after that point.

What do I need to do next?

Comment: I think B.Mackey's answer is great. But I guess another way to do this problem is to expand $f$ as a power series at some point. The power series should have an infinite radius of convergence since $f$ is entire. Then, you can use the differential equation to conclude that the coefficient matches that of $e^z$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: Differentiate $\displaystyle \frac{f(z)}{e^z}$

Comment: @mackey and Braindead:thanks